error in displaying time difference in hh:mm:ss
I am trying to display the difference between a start and end time in hh:mm:ss. The calculation doesnt seem to work properly.
I used the following code:
TimeDiff = 
VAR FirstDateStart =
    MINX ( unit_task_timestamps, unit_task_timestamps[NEW] )
VAR LastDateEnd =
    MAXX ( unit_task_timestamps, unit_task_timestamps[TASK_STATUS_ENROUTE] )
RETURN
    FORMAT ( LastDateEnd - FirstDateStart, "hh:mm:ss" )

Below is an image of the result:


Is this the same question you posted earlier? You shouldn't create a new question for the same problem but just edit the original: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78884879/display-time-difference-in-hhmmss

Is that code computing the difference between the earliest timestamp and the latest timestamp?  If so, then it's no surprise that every row gets the same value.

@TimRoberts, The earliest timestamp is "NEW"  and latest timestamp is "TASK_STATUS_ENROUTE". I dont understand why every row is getting the same value.

Because they work on the entire column.  There's going to one single value for FirstDateStart, which is the smallest of all the rows.  That one single value will be placed in all the rows.

This question is similar to: display time difference in hh:mm:ss. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Every row is getting the same value because the calculation is looking at all values/rows in the NEW and TASK_STATUS_ENROUTE columns and finding the minimum and maximum (this is what MINX and MAXX do, they look at the entire column). Try:
TimeDiff = FORMAT(unit_task_timestamps[TASK_STATUS_ENROUTE] - unit_task_timestamps[NEW], "hh:mm:ss")

you can try this
TimeDiff = 
VAR FirstDateStart =
    MAX(unit_task_timestamps[NEW] )
VAR LastDateEnd =
    MAX( unit_task_timestamps[TASK_STATUS_ENROUTE] )
RETURN
    FORMAT ( LastDateEnd - FirstDateStart, "hh:mm:ss" )

